# Require Documentation topic titles to be unique

Tags: feature-request, documentation, suggested-edits

I think that titles for both Topics and Examples within the same Topic should be unique.

Currently, it's possible to create Topics of the same name.

---

There is already an Android Intent Topic but creating another one is possible:

> Proposed Change *(retracted)*

[image: Image 1]

Comment: This. You could even go further and show similar topics, just like when asking a question. This would reduce the duplicate topics *considerably*, which is already a problem in huge (100+) tags.

Comment: Very good idea. However the problem of too many similar examples and topics remains.

Answer (score 2):

As one of the presumably many people who actively search information from the Documentation - this would be a fantastic and eminently helpful move, at the very least saving a lot of time in finding specific documentation with specific keywords.

However, as @Trilarion commented, similar examples could make this very difficult.